# Set logical status of CheckBox in matplotlib without triggering callbacks?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

Is there a way to set the logical status of CheckButtons in matplotlib withput triggering `onclick()` callbacks?

Here is my scenario:

I am displaying a graph with a large number of traces (50+) and want to give the user the option of displaying a subset of these on the basis of some fixed queries, which the user selects via `CheckButton`.  Every time a button is clicked the the script gets the status of all present `CheckButton`s via `get_status()`, computes the indices of the traces that meet the selected criteria, and updates the display accordingly.

In order to make life easier for the user I want to also have a "Select all" and "Clear all" buttons.  The best way I can come up with to implement these is to force the logical state of all CheckButtons to True or False without triggering an `on_click()` callback, then set the visibility of the traces accordingly.

However, `CheckButton()` does not have a `set_status()` method
https://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.CheckButtons

There is a `set_active()` method but according the documetnation it triggers a callback if `eventson` is true.

Can someone give me a couple of pointers how to go about doing this?  Do I need to set `eventson=False` for the wdget, then `set_active()=True` followed by `eventson=True`?  Seems rather clunky, but I can't figure a more elegant way, even after spending way too many hours.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**I knew it**, as soon as I post a question I figure out the answer.  Here is what I came up with for anyone else that wants to do something like this

> ```
>     check.eventson = False
>     status = check.get_status()
>     for i,stat in enumerate(status):
>         if ((enable and not stat) or (not enable and stat)): 
>             check.set_active(i)
>     check.eventson = True
> ```

here check is a reference to the `CheckBox()` object and `enable` is a variable set to `True` if you want to enable all checkboxes, or `False` otherwise.